# How can I use a different zoom on different displays in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, zoom

I have a Windows 8 15" laptop with a 1920x1080 screen resolution. At that size, everything is really small. In the "Screen Resolution" configuration window, I click on the link "Make text and other items larger or smaller" and from there I can change the size of all items to 125% or 150% to make them bigger on the screen.

I have a 22" screen that is connected via hdmi to my laptop. The screen resolution is also 1920x1080 and on this screen, everything looks good when the display is at 100%.

Here's my question: is there any way I can have a different "zoom" for each screens?

I'd like to have my laptop display at 150% and my "external" screen at 100%. One way to do it is to change the screen resolution of my laptop screen to 1600x900 but then the text gets all blurry so it's not a good solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Windows 8.1 will allow me to do exactly what I want according to this:

http://liliputing.com/2013/07/windows-8-1-to-offer-better-support-for-high-res-displays-multi-monitor-setups.html

So the solution is to wait a month or so...

Answer (score 0):

No, as of right now, from my understanding, you can't do this through any version of Microsoft Windows.

But another piece of software? Maybe, but I doubt it exists. Good question though.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't actually work. Win 8 will allow different Zoom (ie scaling) settings for different monitors but it will NOT allow you to set them. In other words, you'll have to be happy with Windows decision of what your scaling/DPI settings should be.